# Unable to build Spring maven project, issue in POM.XMl file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a project New -> Spring Stater Project. then fill the facts then press the finish.
After that in POM.xml file shows small red x mark when I open it red x mark at the  tag.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Error :

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   com.dasun:HotelReservation:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.5.RELEASE
>   from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was   cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are   forced. Original
>   error: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.5.RELEASE
>   from/to   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect
>   timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

How to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You can got to , go to `~/.m2/repository/` directory, go to`com/dasun` and remove / rename the `HotelReservation` directory , and retry

Comment: Where s that .m2 located?

Comment: home directory.

Comment: Actually did not get you correctly sir.

Comment: one way to find this out, @D.Anush
right click on your project, go to "properties", on the left go to "Java Build Path", on the middle top click on "Libraries", on the middle list find "Maven"/ "Maven Dependencies".
disclose it and you should able to figure out where is the path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, you can use spring initializr which will generate a basic project structure for you based on the build system you choose(**Maven for your case**).

All you need to do is select all the dependencies needed for your spring boot project and click on generate the project. After downloading, extract and import the project to your IDE.project downloaded will contain pom.xml with the dependencies you have selected and required configuration for the project.
check out this link for spring initializer: https://start.spring.io/

[image: Screenshot of Spring Initializr]
**steps:**

1. select the build system (Maven or Gradle)
2. select Spring boot version
3. fill the fields Group ID and Artifact ID
4. Finally, select the dependencies for your project and click on Generate project.
5. Extract the ZIP file downloaded and import the project to your IDE.the project downloaded will have basic pom.xml with the dependencies you have selected and required configuration for the project.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the `<relativePath/>`-tag, maven attempts to read the parent pom from a relative path on your hard drive while no relative path is specified. Removing the tag should fix the problem:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Maven will now download the parent pom from Maven Central.